# Print current data.frame line aka progress in purrr:::pmap

Tags: r, dataframe, purrr, pmap

I'm trying to understand [purrr](/questions/tagged/purrr) and I'm currently working with [pmap](/questions/tagged/pmap). `pmap` can be used to call a predefined function and uses the values in a [dataframe](/questions/tagged/dataframe) as arguments to the function call. I would like to know what the current state is, as my data.frames might have several 1000s of rows.

How can I print the current line, that `pmap` is running on, possibly together with the total length of the data.frame?

I tried to include a counter like in a for loop and also tried to capture the current row using

`current <- data.frame(...)`

and then `row.names(current)`

(idea from here: https://blog.az.sg/posts/map-and-walk/)

but in both cases it always prints `1`.

Thanks for helping.

For reproducibilty let's use the code from the question that brought me to `purrr:::pmap` ([How to use expand.grid values to run various model hyperparameter combinations for ranger in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60945003/how-to-use-expand-grid-values-to-run-various-model-hyperparameter-combinations-f/60946478?noredirect=1#comment107830970_60946478)):

```r
library(ranger)
data(iris)
Input_list <- list(iris1 = iris, iris2 = iris)  # let's assume these are different input tables

# the data.frame with the values for the function
hyper_grid <- expand.grid(
  Input_table = names(Input_list),
  Trees = c(10, 20),
  Importance = c("none", "impurity"),
  Classification = TRUE,
  Repeats = 1:5,
  Target = "Species")

# the function to be called for each row of the `hyper_grid`df
fit_and_extract_metrics <- function(Target, Input_table, Trees, Importance, Classification, ...) {
  RF_train <- ranger(
    dependent.variable.name = Target, 
    data = Input_list[[Input_table]],  # referring to the named object in the list
    num.trees = Trees, 
    importance = Importance, 
    classification = Classification)  # otherwise regression is performed

  data.frame(Prediction_error = RF_train$prediction.error,
             True_positive = RF_train$confusion.matrix[1])
}

# the pmap call using a row of hyper_grid and the function in parallel
hyper_grid$res <- purrr::pmap(hyper_grid, fit_and_extract_metrics)
```

I tried two things:

```r
counter <- 0
fit_and_extract_metrics <- function(Target, Input_table, Trees, Importance, Classification, ...) {
  counter <- counter + 1
  print(paste(counter, "of", nrow(hyper_grid)))
  # rest of the function
}

# and also 
fit_and_extract_metrics <- function(Target, Input_table, Trees, Importance, Classification, ...) {
  current <- data.frame(...)
  print(paste(row.names(current), "of", nrow(hyper_grid)))
  # rest of the function
}

# both return
> hyper_grid$res <- purrr::pmap(hyper_grid, fit_and_extract_metrics)
[1] "1 of 40"
[1] "1 of 40"
[1] "1 of 40"
...
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Please show the code you actually tried.

Comment: @MrFlick: Yes I was a little lazy, I thought it might be a common task where you need no data. But I added an example and also the two things I tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are already using pmap, the easiest way would just be to pass the rownames as well.

You can do something like

```
hyper_grid$res <- purrr::pmap(cbind(hyper_grid, .row=rownames(hyper_grid)), fit_and_extract_metrics)
```

which just adds a `.row` vector with the row names. And then in your iterating function, you can do

```
fit_and_extract_metrics <- function(Target, Input_table, Trees, Importance, Classification, ..., .row) {
  print(paste(.row, "of", nrow(hyper_grid)))
  # rest of the function
}
```

Notice that I added a `.row` parameter to the function to capture that new column we added.

Note that `map()` and `walk()` have versions that make getting the iterator a bit easier called `imap()` and `iwalk()`, but the `pmap` does not have an `ipmap` presumably because you have to do all the work building the list of parameters that it just makes sense to pass in the names or indexes that you want as well.

Comment: ok this works perfectly, but there is quite a lot about purrr I have to figure out. Thanks for showing me how to feed more information into the function call!